# How can I set my system to suspend when inactive to a longer amount of time

Tags: unity, power-management, suspend, settings

I run Mythtv on some Ubuntu 11.10 based machines.

In the power settings, I can choose from a list of time periods from 5 minutes up to 1 hour for the the machine to suspend when inactive.  I would like to set the suspend to occur at a longer interval, like 2 hours or 4.

Previously with Gnome, I would think that I could go into the gconf editor and find the key there, I am not sure with Unity where to override a setting like this.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You can try with `dconf-editor`. If you don't find it install it with

```
sudo apt-get install dconf-tools
```

then run it searching for `dconf Editor` in Dash or typing `dconf-editor` from the alt+f2 command line. The power settings are stored in

```
org → gnome → settings-daemon → plugins → power
```

To set the timeout when plugged in change the **sleep-inactive-ac-timeout** option, to set the timeout when on battery change **sleep-inactive-battery-timeout**.

These options are indicated in waiting seconds before suspend (so a value of 14400 will suspend the system after 4 hours).

[image: dconf-editor in ubuntu]

Comment: This still works in 18.04 bionic in April 2018 even though dconf-editor has new layout. Awesome!

Comment: For a simple command-line, that should also work:

`gsettings set org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.power sleep-inactive-ac-timeout 10800`

to set the timeout to 3 hours e.g. (tested on Fedora 30, but I gues it also works on Ubuntu)

Comment: In Ubuntu 20.04, you have to install the following `sudo apt install dconf-editor`