# Changing suspend timer to more than 1 hour

Tags: power-management, suspend, gnome-power-manager

In Ubuntu 13.10, I want to change my suspend timer to go to sleep after 3 hours, but in System Settings I can not do that.
I'm wondering is there any way to set it? 
I've already tried the instructions in this question: https://askubuntu.com/questions/74628/enabling-longer-period-of-inactivity-before-suspending

Comment: Did you saw this answer which that question was duplicated to? http://askubuntu.com/a/99011/169736

Comment: honestly I've searched A lot but I didn't see this post . thanks

Comment: Did that answered your question?

Comment: I've done everything has been said in the post , I have to wait to see if it will suspend after more than 1 hour , but I think it'll work , thanks to you .